# are the integrals and bounds correct for $P(X \gt Y)$ and $P(Y \gt \frac12 | X \lt \frac12)$ of the joint probability function

Tags: probability, random-variables

$$f(x,y)=\frac67(x^2+\frac{xy}{2}) \qquad 0 \lt x \lt 1,\qquad 0 \lt y \lt 2$$
find $P(X \gt Y)$  and $P(Y \gt \frac12 | X \lt \frac12)$
I know how to calulate the integral I am just not sure if I set the integrals up correctly

for $P(X \gt Y)$ I have
$$\int_0^1\int_0^x \frac67(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dy dx$$

and for $P(Y \gt \frac12 | X \lt \frac12)$ I have 
$$\int_0^\frac12\int_\frac12^2 \frac67(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dy dx$$

Are these integrals and bounds correct?

Comment: The second integral is $P(Y \gt \frac12, X \lt \frac12)$, not $P(Y \gt \frac12 \mid X \lt \frac12)$. Apart from that, this is correct.

Comment: there should be a difference between the intersection $P(Y \gt \frac12 , X \lt \frac12)$ and the conditional $P(Y \gt \frac12 | X \lt \frac12)$ because that is how it was written in my homework? or does the conditional in this case not make sense and my professor just made a typo?

Comment: Why do you feel necessary to hypothetize a typo by your professor? A reflex reaction?

Comment: i am asking you if it could be a typo since you told me that it should be an intersection when on paper it was a conditional probability, so i am just asking if it taking a conditional probability of a joint probability density makes sense

Comment: No, I noted that you were computing $P(Y>\frac12,X<\frac12)$ while you were asked the value of $P(Y>\frac12\mid X<\frac12)$, and you reacted to this explanation by asking out of the blue whether "the conditional in this case (did) not make sense and (your) professor just made a typo." The hypothesis that your professor made a typo is not needed to explain the exercise.

Comment: so to find the conditional probability is it simply: $\frac{P(Y \gt \frac12, X \lt \frac12)}{P(X \lt \frac12)}$ where for $P(X \lt \frac12)$ i would find and use the marginal distribution of X?

Comment: Yes. $ $ $ $ $ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$P(Y \gt \frac12 , X \lt \frac12) = \int_0^\frac12\int_\frac12^2 \frac67(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dy dx$$

$$P(Y \gt \frac12 | X \lt \frac12) = \frac{\int_0^\frac12\int_\frac12^2 \frac67(x^2+\frac{xy}{2})dy dx}{P(X \lt \frac12)}$$

To compute $P(X \lt \frac12)$, we must get the marginal distribution of $X$:

$$f_X(x) = \int_0^2 f(x,y) dy$$

Now we have

$$P(X \lt \frac12) = \int_0^1 f_X(x) 1_{(-\infty, 1/2)} dx$$

$$ = \int_0^{1/2} f_X(x) dx$$

$$ = \int_0^{1/2} \int_0^2 f(x,y) dy dx$$